# How to set scheduler in php with cron

Tags: php, mysql, cron

1. My CRON job is running every 5 min on server.
2. **I want to run a function through a CRON when it will satisfy below criteria**:

   1. I want to set a scheduler with following options which user will select:

      Start Date & Time: user will select start date & time for scheduler

      Scheduler recurrence : daily/weekly/monthly (User can select from dropdrown)

      Scheduler to run number of times: 1 to 24 (User can select from dropdrown)
          (Ex. 1: function will run 6 times daily, Ex. 2: function will run 2 times weekly, etc...)

I'm storing all the above thing in DB in the below table format (You can correct me there if anything wrong, or with the new table format:
[image: scheduler_master table]

I did following things: (I'm calling run_sm_cron() this function in cron)

```
    public function run_sm_cron() {
        $scheduler_data = $this->admin_model->get_scheduler();  // Get all records of scheduler

        foreach ($scheduler_data as $scheduler) {   // I have 5-6 records in db, it will go through each records
            if ($run_at = $this->is_active_for_cron($scheduler)) {  // Here, for this logic i need help
                // This function ( is_active_for_cron() )check for the scheduler criteria, if satisfied then will enter here.
                // If rec_period is daily and rec_period is 12, 
                //then control should come in this function 12 times daily from the cron which is running after each 5 min


                // here i'm doing my other imp things to set
            }
        }

    }

    public function is_active_for_cron($scheduler) {
        // get_db_date() : this is custom function, which returns date in expected format

        $current_time = get_db_date();  
        $start_date = get_db_date($scheduler['start_date'] . $scheduler['start_time']);
        if ($start_date <= $current_time) {
            $recurrence_pattern = $scheduler['recurrence_pattern'];
            $recurrence_period = $scheduler['recurrence_period'];
            $run_status = $scheduler['run_status']; // Check how many times ran already 

            switch ($recurrence_pattern) {
            case 'Daily': {
                        $total_time = 24 * 60;  //Convert in minutes
                        $recurrence_time = floor(24 / $recurrence_period) * 60;

                        $add_time = $recurrence_time * $run_status * 60;

                        $add_next_time = $recurrence_time * ($run_status + 1) * 60; // i'm checking for next time to run as per schedule
                        $run_at = date("H:i", strtotime($start_date) + $add_time);
                        $run_at = get_db_date(get_db_date('', DATE_YMD) . $run_at); // Get time and date to run next time

                        $run_next_at = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+" . ($recurrence_time / 60) . " hours", strtotime($current_time)));

                    if ($recurrence_period == $run_status) {   // stop execution in before last scheduler,...adjustment
                        $this->admin_model->cron_run_completed($scheduler['api_id'], 0);    
                        // Run scheduler n number of times, after completed n numbers make it 0....To know how many times to run or to stop
                    }

                    if (strtotime($current_time) > strtotime($run_at) && strtotime($current_time) < strtotime($run_next_at)) {
                        // If current time is grater than run at   and current time is less than next running time

                        $this->admin_model->cron_run_completed($scheduler['api_id']);   // increment run_times in db...To know how many times it ran already 
                        return $run_at; // return true if control comes here
                    }




                        break;
            }

            case 'Weekly': {


                break;
            }

            case 'Monthly': {


                break;
            }

        }

    }
```

I'm calling run_sm_cron() through CRON, so i want to get true as per scheudler from is_active_for_cron(), so that i can get my job done.

> Ex: I want to run a cron daily with 12 times, where as my cron is
>   running every 5 min, So is_active_for_cron() this functino should
>   return true 12 times a day.

*(This 12 times will be dynamic can change from 1 to 24 and 'daily' can change to weekly or monthly depend on user selection)*

Comment: You told us what you want, told us what you did, but forgot to tell us what your problem is!

Comment: I've tried to improve the formatting a bit, but it seems like you forgot where you were going with that too somewhere in the middle there.

Comment: @Jeff
I have added what i want with example, please check once.

Comment: @glennsl Thank for the formatting, and please check the last example that I have added for more clarification.